# Python: tracing lines of source code that python function activates

Tags: python, function, file, open-source, inspect

I am aware of how to find the location of a python function in its source code with the `inspect` module via

```
import inspect
inspect.getsourcefile(random_function)
```

However, *while* a python function is running, or *after* it has run, how would one find all of the pieces of the source code it utilized/referenced during its individual run?

For ex., if I ran `random_function(arg1=1, arg2=2)` vs. `random_function(arg1=1, arg5=3.5)`, I would like to know which different parts of the module got used each time.

Is there anything like the example [here](http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2005/04/20/tracing_python_code.html)?

Comment: I don't think you can do that as all of function scope will be garbage collected when the function exits. Would it be enougt to collect the function name and arguments at the function call?

Comment: I am thinking of doing this to better understand how a large python library that I am contributing to works, and knowing which areas of the library "light up" after functions are called with minor edits would be extremely useful, imho.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting the information of bytecode using [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module. For instance:

```
import dis
import numpy as np

def main():
    array = np.zeros(shape = 5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(dis.dis(main))
```

result:

```
  5           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (np)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                1 (zeros)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (('shape',))
              8 CALL_FUNCTION_KW         1
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (array)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```